# Grails service methods to expose as REST services

Tags: grails, grails-services

I am new to Grails. I have seen how to expose the controller actions/methods as RESTFull services using UrlMapping.groovy file and using GET/POST/PUT/DELETE http methods.

Now following is my questions.

1.Is there any way exposing the service class methods (/service folder in Grails apps) as RESTFull services and access them in similar way as i accessed the controller actions as described above.

2.Is there a way to expose the service class methods as SOAP services?

Comment: If you want to make Service class as Rest Service you could do that by having a wrapper method in controller as you need to create one or more controllers to handle RESTful requests and responses as Service class can't handle http requests.

Answer (score 5):

You would like to look at [JAXRS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jaxrs) and [CXF plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf/) and [this page](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/webServices.html) for reference, if you have not transitioned to Grails 2.3 yet.

Grails 2.3.0 comes with a [renaissance of REST](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html) services.

*Note*
JAXRS plugin will help in achieving what you needed from question # 1 agreeing to the comment from @TP_JAVA about exposing service methods as controller action.